# How do I create an intent when I only have an optional context?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

In the following code (which should start the MainActivity on boot):

```
class autostart : BroadcastReceiver() {
    companion object {
        val TAG = "myapp-autostart"
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "context: $context, intent: $intent")
        if (context != null) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent
```

I'm assuming that this is related to context being a "Context?", but I have been writing Kotlin for 15 minutes so far, so I know nothing.

Comment: Try passing not `this` into `Intent(this,...)` but a `context` parameter.

Comment: try with `context.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @Demigod - Thanks, that was it, plus I also needed to pass the context explicitly into startActivity too.  If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's small mistake in your code: while you're checking `context` parameter, you're still passing `this` into `Intent()`. Change your code to use `context` instead.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "context: $context, intent: $intent")
    if (context != null) {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Also, you have two variable called `intent` (parameter and method variable), you can call them differently to not mistakenly use other one.

Comment: do startActivity method accept context in it's parameter ? cause i am looking it docs and [read](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) but there is nothing like it accept context

Comment: @Ashish, you're right. there's no need to pass a context into startActivity

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted the answer, but a single argument version of `startActivity` does not exist for me when compiling for Android 6.  There is a three argument version, which takes (context, intent, options) from  android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity but it doesn't work.  I'll go back to Java and solve it there first.

Comment: @Demigod - I made it work in Kotlin and have edited your code to reflect the minor changes required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
It launches the activity defined as launcher activity:

```
val launchIntent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(APP_PACKAGE_NAME)
if (launchIntent != null) {
    context.startActivity(launchIntent)
}
```